# Sinatra + Bundler?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler

I'm wondering how one can use Bundler with Sinatra. The idea is to use the gems that Bundler downloads inside the .gems folder.

Comment: Yehuda Katz has a great article about using bundler today: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/03/using-the-new-gem-bundler-today/

Comment: Also, the bundler documentation itself has a good example of how to setup a sinatra application  http://gembundler.com/sinatra.html and it is current.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the best way is described [here](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/using-the-rubygems-bundler-for-your-app/) on EngineYard blog:

```
# This makes sure the bundled gems are in our $LOAD_PATH
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'vendor', 'gems', 'environment'))

# This actually requires the bundled gems
Bundler.require_env

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  # stuff
end
```

Answer (score 48):

Inside your Sinatra app, you just have to require the bundler setup:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "sinatra"

get "/" do
  "Hello world!"
end
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to add the additional `require "bundler/setup"` at the top of your app, you can instead invoke sinatra via `bundle exec` (e.g. `bundle exec ruby myapp.rb`)

This assumes that you have a `Gemfile` in the root of your application.  It might look like this:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
```

This also assumes that you've already installed bundler (`gem install bundler`) and that you ran `bundle install` to install all the gem dependencies.

Comment: if you use Bundler.require :defaults there's no need to manually require 'sinatra' or other gems

Answer (score 10):

As my original answer was quite old but there seems to be still attention to this topic here's the latest version of bundler/sinatra setup which will cover most of the use case:

A minimal `config.ru`

```
require './my_sinatra_app'
run MySinatraApp
```

An environment `env.rb` file that requires all the bundled gems (also supports loading the current environment's group):

```
require 'bundler/setup'

APP_ENV = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"

Bundler.require :default, APP_ENV.to_sym
```

Then your app file (requiring the environment) with your sinatra app (`Sinatra::Base`):

```
require_relative 'env'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

Start your development server with rackup, and Sinatra will be loaded via Bundler, your app will be accessible from http://localhost:9292.

```
$ rackup
```

or `bundle exec rackup` if needed

Make sure you have a Gemfile like the following one and you run the `bundle` command before starting the app

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"

gem "puma" # a better rack server than the default webrick
```

Answer (score 8):

+1 for the [guide on the bundler website](http://gembundler.com/sinatra.html), but if you have a simple app and use Sinatra's dsl at the top level, then you need to do the following:

in your Gemfile (tell bundler not require sinatra):

```
gem 'sinatra', :require => false
```

and in the app's file (explicitly require sinatra):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'hello world'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To use bundler with a Sinatra application, you only need to do two things. First, create a Gemfile.

`gem 'sinatra'`

Then, set up your config.ru file to load the bundle before it loads your Sinatra app.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require './my_sinatra_app'
run MySinatraApp
```

Start your development server with rackup, and Sinatra will be loaded via Bundler.

`rackup`

[source bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.3/sinatra.html)