# Sinatra, Bundler and BUNDLE_PATH confusion

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundle, bundler

I am having trouble configuring Sinatra to use Bundler. I am confused as to where Gems should be being installed? I've read both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706120/sinatra-bundler) and this [documentation](http://gembundler.com/sinatra.html).

My `Gemfile` looks like:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "sinatra"
gem "amazon-ec2"
```

My `config.ru` looks like:

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup
require "application"
run Sinatra::Application
```

My `application.rb` looks like:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
require "AWS"

#... rest of application
```

Now, when I run `bundle install` everything works correctly and Gems get installed into `~/.bundle/` in my home directory. Yet, in my app if I have a look at `.bundle/config` it shows:

```
--- 
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: ""
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/gems
```

Sure enough, when I start up the app (using Passenger by the way) it says:

```
Could not find gem 'amazon-ec2 (>= 0, runtime)' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Clearly `bundle install` is installing Gems in a different place to where Sinatra expects them to be. Does that mean I have to use `bundle install vendor` or reconfigure something else so that the application expects the Gems to be in `~/.bundle`?

Comment: What version of bundler are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.9.26. I have managed to get things working locally by always explicitly putting gems into `vendor/gems` rather than my home directory with `bundle install vendor/gems`. However, I also had a devil's own job getting it to deploy to my server - Sinatra seems incapable of loading some gems from the system location, and some from `vendor/gems` at the same time - AFAICT, all gems need to be loaded from the same location. Bundler works effortlessly with Rails 3, but seems a nightmare with Sinatra. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong :(

Answer (score 2):

About a year after @aaronrussell 's initial posting, I hit the same problem with Passenger, Nginx, Bundler, Sinatra. I got through it by running this on production:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

Bundled gems go in ./vendor/bundle

Here are some details on [bundler deployment mode](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE)